# Magento2 - localhost/Magento2/admin/ cant be reached

Tags: magento2

http://localhost/Magento2/admin

Can't be reached on `Windows10` server after successful `Magento2` installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Magento doesn't work with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Baseurl** and **Baseurl secure**

**Change From :-**

> localhost

**To** :-

> 127.0.0.1

**Then Run This Command :-**

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**OR Execute Query in Database:-**

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```